# React: Axios PATCH request's .then() handler is not executing even if the PATCH request is successful

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I am trying to make a PATCH request using Axios package from my React frontend to my Node server.

The PATCH request works fine. It is hitting the Node backend successfully.

But, I have attached a .then() handler that I want to execute if the PATCH request is successful. But, that's not happening. It simply doesn't execute.

```
        axios.patch("/notes/"+id, toggledNote)
        .then((value)=>{
            console.log("Patch request has been made.");  //This is not printed even if PATCH request is successful
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            console.log("Failure: PATCH request to server");
        })
```

I have a Axios POST request elsewhere in my code. The .then() handler is working fine there.

Not sure why the .then() handler is not working for my Axios PATCH request.

Comment: Can you try using the async await pattern and see what's the result of the axios.patch request you are making?

Comment: I was just about to mention what @cEeNiKc said here. axios requests are asynchronous, so your function can return before the request is actually completed if you don't wrap this call in an async function, or simply return the request within a function. If you make the function where this call occurs async and the "await" the request OR return it within the function I think that will solve your problem.

Comment: Actually @SimeonIkudabo the reason I was asking him to check using async await pattern is just to check if the request is actually successful. Otherwise .then and .catch pattern should work fine and print the console.log if request succeeds. Here is a quick example https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-brook-s0vvd?file=/src/App.js